# How do i include other files containing function from different directory in Python?

Tags: python, file, directory, subdirectory

I want to include all files in `my_lib` as the directory will contains most used function per library. In this case i want to import `my_pandas.py`.

I already add the library directory `my_lib` which contains `__init__.py` and `my_pandas.py`.

However i cannot run the following command:
`from my_lib import my_pandas`

How can i run `from my_lib import my_pandas` command?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finding your own custom modules in Python is unfortunately a little fiddly.

You have correctly made `my_lib` into a module by adding `__init__.py`. There are two ways to get the module to import correctly, but they boil down to the same thing: the module needs to appear as a subdirectory inside a directory that is in your path.

Therefore your solutions are:

1. navigate to `/home/inetvmart/python_apps` and run your notebook there instead of inside `/home/inetvmart/python_apps/my_lib` (the current directory is always included in the path, and `my_lib` will be a subdirectory inside your current directory in this case)
2. add `/home/inetvmart/python_apps` *rather than* `/home/inetvmart/python_apps/my_lib` to your path (then the parent directory will be in the path. Therefore your custom module will be a subdirectory in a directory that is in your path)

In this particular case, then, you can probably just change your second cell to: `sys.path.append("/home/inetvmart/python_apps")`

---

I must warn you that this is a somewhat ... hacky ... approach (modifying the path inside a Python script to ensure your imports succeed).

In the medium term, you may like to do something like:

- create a folder called e.g. `/home/<your username>/my_python_modules`
- put this path into the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable (which you could set in your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`/other file)

Then you will be able to import the custom modules inside `my_python_modules` from anywhere on your machine.